# Choosing a correct collisionshape for a voxel engine

Tags: ogre, bullet-physics, voxels

I am building a voxel engine on Ogre with bullet as a physics engine.

I separated my blocks into chunks to help batch together render calls.

At the moment, each chunk's physics is handled by a btBvhTriangleMeshShape that is constructed through the vertices and indices.

Each time the user breaks a voxel, I modify the vertex and index array and construct a new btBvhTriangleMeshShape.

Unfortunately, because btBvhTriangleMeshShape has to recreate an optimizedBVH each time it is created, this becomes quite slow, taking several seconds each time the user breaks a block.

I've alternatively tried using a btConvexTriangleMeshShape, but the broadphase collision detection now becomes very low performance dropping the fps to single digits if the player is near the blocks.

What is the proper collisionshape to choose?

Comment: [Make your own](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/27463/7191)

Comment: Are you multithreading the recreation of the arrays?

Comment: @JasonCoombes, I'm not. While I should, it wouldn't solve the core issue. If I multithread it, it won't freeze the game anymore, but it would still have the problem of the block taking a second before disappearing.

Comment: If you reduce the chunk array to a view distance of say 3 from camera/player/world origin, does the recreation in singlethread still take 1 second? If you temporarily remove the physics engine from the generation/tesselation, is it still taking 1 second?

Comment: If possible, consider pre-calculating shatter forms. If you can't reliably do that, consider pre-calculating a few shapes to pick from. It all really depends on what your game needs to do.

Comment: @jason, the latency is isolated purely to btBvhTriangleMeshShape's generation of optimized bvh structure. Creation of the graphical mesh is very fast. If I reduce the sizes of chunks, this creation is no longer as slow, but rendering speed suffers.

Comment: @Razor, I thought as much. I can't provide much input then, as many of the voxel engines I've created over the years are in XNA, not Ogre. I was thinking more generally than of the btBvhTriangleMeshShape's generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive decided to use compoundshape and construct boxcollisionshapes for each block. I've done some optimization to only build collisionshapes for visible blocks.

As requested, here's some more information:

1. For each Chunk I create a
   `OgreBulletCollisions::CompoundCollisionShape`
2. For each visible Block inside each Chunk I construct a
   `OgreBulletCollisions::BoxCollisionShape` of the proper size.
3. Next I call `CompoundCollisionShape`'s `addChildShape` function to
   add the `BoxCollisionShape` to the `CompoundCollisionShape`.
4. When all the box shapes are added I create a `RigidBody` out of the
   `CompoundCollisionShape`

As for the optimization:

1. I build the chunk with Ogre3d's `ManualObject`
2. I iterate through every block inside a chunk and then iterate
   through all of the 6 sides of the block
3. For each side, I check if there's a block adjacent to that side. If
   so, that means the side is obscured and do not need to be rendered.
4. If all 6 sides of a block are all obscured, then the block need not
   have a collision shape attached to it.
5. Recalculate as necessary if chunks are modified.

Comment: can you elaborate some more?

Comment: Sure thing, I just updated my question with some more information

Answer (score 1):

So couple of things to keep in mind here, typically physics engines are built with the assumption that objects are not added/removed as much as would happen with voxel engines.  Not only do you have to update when they change the terrain, but you are going to be constantly removing/adding chunks as they walk around the world.  The other thing to consider is that the physics engine keeps it's own copy of all the shapes in an oct-tree.  Meaning you're going to have two copies of all the geometry floating around in memory, which can be expensive.

Also, with all the adding and removing you'll be doing, you have to consider that octtrees are not so great at the adding and removing part.  They are great for spatial lookups, but slower to update.  Now it's perfectly possible to still do all of this, but these are some good things to keep in mind.